# A Residue problem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Preparing myself for qualifying exam, I found this problem in residues in some previous qualifying exam, and I am stuck and don't know how to solve it, any helps?
$$f(z)=(ze^{2-z}+(2-z)e^z)e^{(z-1)^{2}+(z-1)^{-2}}  $$ at z = 1

Comment: Tip: you can focus on just the $e^{\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}}$ part.

Comment: @user2520938: There is a $(z-1)^{-2}$ in the last exponent.

Comment: @el_tenedor haha of course... didn't look close enough

Comment: @krvolok This part has essential singularity at z=1, what could I deduce?

Comment: @Fabian Have you tried a Laurent-series expansion?

Comment: @el_tenedor Yes, I tried it, but it was complicated, so I thought it would not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a back-of-the-envelope calculation using Laurent-series expansion at $z=1$, i.e

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n (z-1)^{n}.$$

Since you are only interested in $a_{-1}$, look at the following:

$$e^{(z-1)^2} = 1 + (z-1)^2 + \dots$$
$$e^{(z-1)^{-2}} = 1 + (z-1)^{-2} + \dots$$

Those are the last two factors expanded at (z-1). What about the first one? Since the factor $g(z) := (ze^{2-z}+(2-z)e^z)$ does not have a singularity at all, the Laurent-series expansion is in fact a Taylor-series expansion. The only term affecting the residual will be the linear term. We calculate the derivative of the first factors as

$$g'(z) = (ze^{2-z}+(2-z)e^z)' = e^{2-z} + (-z) e^{2-z} + (-1) e^z + (2-z) e^z.$$

Evaluating this term at z=1 gives

$$g'(1) = e - e - e + e = 0,$$

hence the Taylor-series has no linear part.

Using the cauchy-product for series you should get that $a_{-1} = 0$. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So whenever we have a product of to factors $f(z)=g(z)h(z)$, s.t. $h(z)$ has singularity at $z_0$ and $g(z)$ does not have, and $g'(z_0)=0$ , then $Res(f(z),z_0)=Res(h(z),z_0)$ ? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Fabian No, just consider $f(z) = h(z) = 1/z$ and $g(z) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same question yesterday, and I gave the following hint:

Write $z:=1+t$ with $t$ near $0$, and look at the resulting expression: It is an *even* function of $t$ in a punctured neighborhood of $t=0$.

In order to close the case I'd just add that in this case the residue has to be $=0$.

Comment: Could you please explain more. What will happen if the function is even?

Comment: @Fabian If the function is even the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ (in the Laurent series valid near 0) will be $0$, hence the residue will be $0$. An other way to see this is that if we approximate the unit-circle contour integral by a Riemann sum with partitions symtetric in $z=0$ we find: $f(z)\Delta_z+f(-z)\Delta_{-z}=f(z)\Delta_z-f(z)\Delta_{z}=0$, hence every such approximation yields $0$, thus the limit and hence the integral are $0$, which means the residue is $0$.